# print a progress-bar processing in Python

Tags: python, printing, progress-bar

I wrote this simple function "processing_flush" in order to print a sequence of points (given by index) to test if my software is processing my data and eventually the speed.
The total size of my data is unknown.

```
    import sys
    import time

    def processing_flush(n, index=5):
        sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing %s" % ((n % index)* "."))
        sys.stdout.flush()

    for n in xrange(20):
        processing_flush(n, index=5)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The problem that i cannot fix is when all points are printed the first time (ex: Processing .... if index is equal to 5) the cursor doesn't start from zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you overwrite the same line again you need to clear at least the positions where the dots are with spaces.

```
def processing_flush(n, index=5):
    sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing %s" % (index * " "))
    sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing %s" % ((n % index)* "."))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The code above may lead to some brief flicker. In your specific case it is sufficient to clear the line when `n % index` becomes 0:

```
def processing_flush(n, index=5):
    if n % index == 0:
        sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing %s" % (index * " "))
    sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing %s" % ((n % index)* "."))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Or even better always write `index-1` characters:

```
def processing_flush(n, index=5):
    sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing %s%s" % ((n % index)* ".", (index - 1 - (n % index))* " "))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

**Edit 1:** Or if you prefer to have the cursor always after the last dot:

```
def processing_flush(n, index=5):
    sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing %s%s" % ((n % index)* ".", (index - 1 - (n % index))* " "))
    sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing %s" % ((n % index)* "."))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

**Edit 2:** Or if you prefer to have the cursor always at the beginning of the line:

```
def processing_flush(n, index=5):
    sys.stdout.write("Processing %s%s\r" % ((n % index)* ".", (index - 1 - (n % index))* " "))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The reason is that your shell remembers the remaining characters of the previous line if you overwrite just the first part of it.

Comment: Wow it was so easy!!. Thanks Johannes, i had spent several hours to surf in google in order to find a solution!!!

Comment: Johannes on my Command prompt of windows looks better the second solution (visually). With the 3) solution the under score cursor of the prompt always goes in the end.

Comment: @Gianni: Combine 3 and 2: Copy the second-last line from solution 2 into solution 3 before the `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Comment: @DanielFrey yes the 2+3 it's the most elegant solution from my point of view

Comment: Ah yes, I see, that is good. What you can also do is append a `\r`at the end of the strings. This will move the cursor always to the beginning of the line. But this is a matter of preference. This also has the advantage that when you print the next line you can overwrite your progress bar. But this is again a matter of preference I guess. I updated the answer according to Daniels suggestion.

Comment: @all: i am happy about this discussion. I was thinking this was a silly question. Thanks all for help

Comment: @JohannesOvermann, when you say at the end of the line is like
sys.stdout.write("Processing %s" % ((n % index)* ".")"\r")?

Comment: No, this was not a silly question at all! :-) We have been sitting there scratching our heads. And I still often do when I see what a terminal can do (or can not do).

Comment: @JohannesOvermann i tested and the only weak part is: when i print really fast the part "Processing" flicker. During this week end i will try to improve :)!!!