# fixing a flicker effect in a ProcessingFlush class of Python used to print a progress-bar processing

Tags: python, class, progress-bar

I have a class ProcessingFlush derived from a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685063/print-a-progress-bar-processing-in-python). I wrote this class in order to print a sequence of points (given by index) to test if my software is processing my data when the size of data is unknown *at priori*.

```
class ProcessingFlush(object):
    def __init__(self, index):
        if index > 70:
            raise ValueError("Index not valid")
        self.index = index

    def update(self, n):
        self._n = n
        self._display()

    def finish(self):
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def start(self):
        sys.stdout.write("Processing")

    def _display(self):
       sys.stdout.write("Processing %s%s\r" % ((n % index)* ".", (index - 1 - (n % index))* " "))
        sys.stdout.flush()

pr = ProcessingFlush(5)
pr.start()
for n in xrange(5000):
    pr.update(n)
pr.finish()
```

the limit of this class is a flicker effect of "Processing" when the processing is really fast. I tried to develop this idea to fix this problem but without results. I wish to create a module start

```
def start(self):
    sys.stdout.write("Processing")
```

where only Processing is printed.

```
def _display(self):
        sys.stdout.write("%s%s%s\r" % ((" " * 10),(self._n % self.index)* ".", (self.index - 1 - (self._n % self.index))* " "))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

display print only the points of processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

class progressBar:
    '''
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/168639/
    Randy Pargman
    Improvements by Kelvie Wong

    Creates a text-based progress bar. Call the object with the `print'
    command to see the progress bar, which looks something like this:

    [=======>        22%                  ]

    You may specify the progress bar's width, min and max values on init.
    '''

    def __init__(self, minValue = 0, maxValue = 100, totalWidth=80):
        self.progBar = '[]'   # This holds the progress bar string
        self.min = minValue
        self.max = maxValue
        self.span = maxValue - minValue
        self.width = totalWidth
        self.amount = 0       # When amount == max, we are 100% done
        self.updateAmount(0)  # Build progress bar string

    def updateAmount(self, newAmount = 0):
        ''' Update the progress bar with the new amount (with min and max
            values set at initialization; if it is over or under, it takes the
            min or max value as a default. '''
        if newAmount < self.min: newAmount = self.min
        if newAmount > self.max: newAmount = self.max
        self.amount = newAmount

        # Figure out the new percent done, round to an integer
        diffFromMin = float(self.amount - self.min)
        percentDone = (diffFromMin / float(self.span)) * 100.0
        percentDone = int(round(percentDone))

        # Figure out how many hash bars the percentage should be
        allFull = self.width - 2
        numHashes = (percentDone / 100.0) * allFull
        numHashes = int(round(numHashes))

        # Build a progress bar with an arrow of equal signs; special cases for
        # empty and full
        if numHashes == 0:
            self.progBar = '[>%s]' % (' '*(allFull-1))
        elif numHashes == allFull:
            self.progBar = '[%s]' % ('='*allFull)
        else:
            self.progBar = '[%s>%s]' % ('='*(numHashes-1),
                                        ' '*(allFull-numHashes))

        # figure out where to put the percentage, roughly centered
        percentPlace = (len(self.progBar) / 2) - len(str(percentDone))
        percentString = str(percentDone) + '%'

        # slice the percentage into the bar
        self.progBar = ''.join([self.progBar[0:percentPlace], percentString,
                                self.progBar[percentPlace+len(percentString):]
                                ])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.progBar)

    def __call__(self, value):
        ''' Updates the amount, and writes to stdout. Prints a carriage return
            first, so it will overwrite the current line in stdout.'''
        print '\r',
        self.updateAmount(value)
        sys.stdout.write(str(self))
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__=='__main__':
    import time
    prog = progressBar(0, 100, 80)
    for i in xrange(101):
        prog.updateAmount(i)
        sys.stdout.write('{p}\r'.format(p=prog))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(.025)
    print
```